# Unable to connect to sqlite file on disk

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Before I asked the question, I have gone through all the posts on this issue that I could find on Stack Overflow.

I have defined the SQLite jdbc drive in my classpath in my maven pom.xml as follows

```
    <!--  SQLite uploads -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

The error stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\zk5426x\AppData\Local\Temp\cms8026785111405543526.db
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

I was able to verify that the file `C:\Users\zk5426x\AppData\Local\Temp\cms8026785111405543526.db`is writable.

My code is as follows:

```
// Writing byte array to the db file.
public Set<CmsXServiceContent> readContentFromSqliteStream(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
       Path path = null;
    try {
      path = Files.createTempFile("cms", ".db");
      if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.info("Temporary file created = " + path.toString());
      }
      try (ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);) {
        Files.copy(is, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      try(
        Connection conn =
            DriverManager.getConnection(
                 "jdbc:sqlite:" +  path.toFile().getCanonicalPath());) {

        // Prepared Statements and result set query.
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Unable to create a temporary file: cms.db");
      throw e;
    } finally {
      if (path != null) {
        path.toFile().deleteOnExit();
      }
    }
}
```

The statement below generates the error. In this statement `C:\Users\zk5426x\AppData\Local\Temp\cms8026785111405543526.db`is writable.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path.getFileName());
```

The code compiles. What I am trying to figure out is how do I resolve this issue? I have added the SQLite-jdbc jar to my classpath with Maven.

**(Update)** Youcef Laidani advised me to delete the binary from .m2 directory. After doing that, and executing the `mvn test` command, I see the following stack trace.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://retail-devops-maven.mycompany.com/content/groups/public/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.7/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://retail-devops-maven.mycompany.com/content/groups/public/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.7/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.pom (5 KB at 3.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://retail-devops-maven.mycompany.com/content/groups/public/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.7/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://retail-devops-maven.mycompany.com/content/groups/public/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.7/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar (3867 KB at 1539.8 KB/sec)

 . . . . . . . . . .  MAVEN LOGS . . . . .  . .

Tests run: 38, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.936 sec 

<<< FAILURE!
testReadContentFromSqliteStream(com.mycompany.cms.tools.service.CmsContentServiceImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.012 sec  <<< FAILURE!
com.mycompany.cms.tools.dao.ContentRetrievalException: Unable to retrieve content for Unable to parse file : cms6986233222629132337.db
    at com.mycompany.cms.tools.service.CmsContentServiceImpl.readContentFromSqliteStream(CmsContentServiceImpl.java:152)
    at com.mycompany.cms.tools.service.CmsContentServiceImplTest.testReadContentFromSqliteStream(CmsContentServiceImplTest.java:75)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\zk5426x\AppData\Local\Temp\cms6986233222629132337.db
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.mycompany.cms.tools.dao.CmsLocalContentDao.readContentsFromResource(CmsLocalContentDao.java:50)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: put the driver manually maybe this can fix your problem

Comment: what did you use netbeans or eclipse?

Comment: I used Eclipse. I have already set up an eclipse workspace with  mvn eclipse:eclipse command.

Comment: ok check your .m2 directory check if your jar is there org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc,,,,.jar existe

Comment: delete also that bd from that directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117474/discussion-between-youcef-laidani-and-kartik).